# Keras: how to check which operation has no gradient defined?

Tags: keras

I encountered an error telling me one of my operation has 'None' for gradient (when running fit, up to fit it's fine, i.e. model builds fine).

The error: ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

How do I find out which operation is producing the error? My model uses custom built layers with backend functions like K.variable (added only during debugging) and K.gather (which I don't think is the source of error since I use it elsewhere). I can't seem to find any suspicious function/operation that could give this error.

Comment: I think, you should check what your custom layers returns, and how your loss function works. Maybe your custom layers always returns the same or a value very around to 0